# react-native-calendars dynamically color dates based on information from API

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm working on a project, which should include calendar and hourly list of reservations in each day. I'm stuck on a problem, where i need to set data from rest api in the markedDates object.

This is the object i get from api

```
{
      "dateTimeFrom":"2020-10-01 00:00:00",
      "dateTimeTo":"2020-10-31 00:00:00",
      "dom":"[\"2020-10-13\"]",
      "dow":"[1,4]",
      "id":"1",
      "transport_id":"1",
      "typeID":"1"
   },
```

The response means, that the reservation is from 2020-10-01 till 2020-10-31, except all Mondays and Thursdays, and also 2020-10-13
dateTime from and To stands for reservation start date and end date,
dom and dow stands for blocked days in a month, dom : '2020-10-13' means that 13th date in 10th month is blocked, and dow : 1,4 stands for all mondays and thursdays are blocked.

Is it possible to achieve this with react-native-calendars, or should i use something else / create custom component?